How to get textContent of a tspan?
I have a problem accessing the textContent of a tspan tag - JS gives a NULL result when executing document.getElementsByTagName("g")[2].getElementsByTagName("tspan")[1].getAttribute("textContent")
However, if I do document.getElementsByTagName("g")[2].getElementsByTagName("tspan")[1]in Chrome's DevConsole, I get the tag and if "Reveal in elements panel" and inspect its properties, those contain textContent with the expected result "green"
How can I get that result with JS?


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  tc = ">"+document.getElementsByTagName("g")[2].getElementsByTagName("tspan")[1].getAttribute("textContent")
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = tc
});
<p>
  textContent=
  <span id="output">
  </span>
</p>    

<svg height="320" width="220">
  <g>
    <rect x="20" y="120" width="79" height="71" transform="translate(20, 120) rotate(NaN) translate(-20, -120)" fill="transparent"></rect><text alignment-baseline="middle" dy="0.7em" x="20" y="120" font-size="11px" fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)" font-style="none" font-weight="0" text-decoration="none" transform="translate(20, 120) rotate(NaN) translate(-20, -120)">
      <tspan x="20" dy="0.7em">RED</tspan>
      <tspan x="20" dy="1em">GREEN</tspan>
      <tspan x="20" dy="1em">BLUE</tspan>
    </text>//
  </g>
  <g>
    <rect x="30" y="140" width="79" height="71" transform="translate(30, 140) rotate(NaN) translate(-30, -140)" fill="transparent"></rect><text alignment-baseline="middle" dy="0.7em" x="30" y="140" font-size="11px" fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" font-style="none" font-weight="0" text-decoration="none" transform="translate(30, 140) rotate(NaN) translate(-30, -140)">
      <tspan x="30" dy="0.7em">RED</tspan>
      <tspan x="30" dy="1em">GREEN</tspan>
      <tspan x="30" dy="1em">BLUE</tspan>
    </text>//
  </g>
  <g>
    <rect x="40" y="160" width="79" height="71" transform="translate(40, 160) rotate(NaN) translate(-40, -160)" fill="transparent"></rect><text alignment-baseline="middle" dy="0.7em" x="40" y="160" font-size="11px" fill="rgb(0, 0, 255)" font-style="none" font-weight="0" text-decoration="none" transform="translate(40, 160) rotate(NaN) translate(-40, -160)">
      <tspan x="40" dy="0.7em">RED</tspan>
      <tspan x="40" dy="1em">GREEN</tspan>
      <tspan x="40" dy="1em">BLUE</tspan>
    </text>//
  </g>
</svg>




textContent is not an attribute - so it's just tc = .....[1].textContent

thanks - Jaromanda, if you answer with your comment, I'll happily accept that!

BTW you should consider using querySelector() as it gives you more flexibility. You could for instance get the text like so let tc = document.querySelector('g:nth-child(3) tspan').textContent

You don't have to use ... .getAttibute("textContent")
JS has a method .textContent which provides the result you want
Your updated code should look like:
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    tc = ">"+document.getElementsByTagName("g")[2].getElementsByTagName("tspan")[1].textContent
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = tc
});



It's not a method
